# How do I compare waveforms from multiple simulations in QuestaSim/ModelSim

Tags: simulation, modelsim, waveform

I want to compare the waveform result from different tets. So basically the test stimulus changes but the unit under test is the same in all cases. What steps do I need to follow to do this?

Essesntially I want to compare the waveforms themself by having them side by side, atleast two of them.

Answer (score 2):

You need to save two waveforms/datasets as .wlf files.  See `'Saving a Simulation to a WLF file'` in the QuestaSim manual.  Then you can compare those separate datasets by going under `Tools > Waveform Compare > Start Comparison`.  Also, see `'Waveform Compare'` in the QuestaSim manual.  It is pretty straight forward.

Answer (score 1):

Comparing waveforms is almost certainly the wrong approach. Better to make the actual testbench code self-checking; let the testbench compare the waveform you get with the expected waveform and signal any errors.

Comment: The idea could be to focus on a signal at some time range and see the difference. Having waveforms i.e a graphical approach looks reasonable to me. The idea is that we have done one simulation and now we want to compare its results with a second simulation.